# Velocity changes due to crystal anharmonicity?

Tags: phonons, anharmonic-oscillators

What is the effect of cubic and higher anharmonicities  of a phonon hamiltonian on the velocity of phonons?

Comment: -1 What research have you done? Have you tried googling your title? see http://nopr.niscair.res.in/bitstream/123456789/9562/1/IJPAP%2042%281%29%2018-24.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Main consequence of anharmonicity is phonon-phonon scattering.

A single phonon means a small amplitude of vibration, it does not get to amplitudes where anharmonicity is important.